# Recode multiple columns to create new columns of df

Tags: r, lapply, recode, dplyr

I am trying to write a function that would mutate multiple columns in a `df` and produce a new column for each recoded variable. In this case the mutation I am running is to subtract each element in the column from 15. I was able to write the following code for three columns, which worked, but in the future I want to run something like this over 20+ columns and writing out each new column name (as you do in mutate) seems burdensome.
I can't seem to get `lapply` to work with a recode or mutate function to produce new columns.

```
df2 <- mutate(df1, new_col1 = 15-old_col1, 
         new_col2 = 15 - old_col2, new_col3 = 15 - old_col3)
```

Comment: You can use mutate_all( ) for that.

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` solution, assuming you want to mutate all of the columns* (see below for a more flexible version).

*as @sb0709 mentions in the comments, `mutate_all` would do this as well.

```
library( data.table )
df <- data.table( old_col_1 = 20:24,
                  old_col_2 = 55:49,
              old_col_3 = rnorm( 5, 100, 30 ) )

df[ , sub( "old", "new", names( df ) ) := lapply( .SD, function(x) 15-x ) ]
```

Which gives:

```
R> df
    old_col_1 old_col_2 old_col_3 new_col_1 new_col_2  new_col_3
 1:        20        55  86.29104        -5       -40  -71.29104
 2:        21        56 144.21564        -6       -41 -129.21564
 3:        22        57 104.84574        -7       -42  -89.84574
 4:        23        58  93.18084        -8       -43  -78.18084
 5:        24        59 104.96188        -9       -44  -89.96188
```

If you want to select less than all of the columns, you just need to subset the `names` vector and the `.SD` list. For example, to run your mutation on only columns 2 and 3:

```
df[ , sub( "old", "new", names( df )[2:3] ) := lapply( .SD[,2:3], function(x) 15-x ) ]
```

Which instead gives:

```
R> df
    old_col_1 old_col_2 old_col_3 new_col_2  new_col_3
 1:        20        55 138.28667       -40 -123.28667
 2:        21        56  69.03836       -41  -54.03836
 3:        22        57 147.39790       -42 -132.39790
 4:        23        58  88.15505       -43  -73.15505
 5:        24        59  28.96437       -44  -13.96437
```